# Changing Data Structure in R using Delimiter

Tags: r

My Input Data set is

df1 = data.frame(Var_A=c('A,B','C'),Var_B=c('1,2','2'))

Desired Output is

df2 = data.frame(Var_A=c('A','A','B','B','C'),Var_B=c('1','2','1','2','2'))

Please help

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cSplit`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
cSplit(df1, "Var B", ",", "long") %>%
    cSplit(., "Var A", ",", "long")
```

---

Or with `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df1, "Var B", convert = TRUE) %>%
      separate_rows("Var A") %>%
      arrange(`Var A`)
#   Var A Var B
#1     A     1
#2     A     2
#3     B     1
#4     B     2
#5     C     2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(`Var A` = c("A,B", "C"), `Var B` = c("1,2", "2"
 )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to solve the problem with your help...God Bless you sir

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a `base` method :

```
cut <- apply(df1, 1, function(x){
  expand.grid(strsplit(x, ","))
})

cut

# [[1]]
#   Var_A Var_B
# 1     A     1
# 2     B     1
# 3     A     2
# 4     B     2
#
# [[2]]
#   Var_A Var_B
# 1     C     2

Reduce(rbind, cut)

#   Var_A Var_B
# 1     A     1
# 2     B     1
# 3     A     2
# 4     B     2
# 5     C     2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was able to solve the problem with your help...God Bless you sir